# get back the write access heroku pg when it crosses the limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am getting error related to `postgresql` on `heroku`. Below is the error

```
PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR: permission denied
```

When I ran `heroku pg:info`, I got below details

```
=== DATABASE_URL
  Plan:        Hobby-dev
  Status:      Available
  Connections: 2/20
  PG Version:  9.4.8
  Created:     2016-02-29 11:38 UTC
  Data Size:   28.4 MB
  Tables:      94
  Rows:        20463/10000 (Write access revoked)
  Fork/Follow: Unsupported
  Rollback:    Unsupported
  Add-on:      postgresql-opaque-25762
```

How can I fix this solution.

Is there any way I can flush/delete some rows from heroku and make it working?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the info in your database, just delete rows / tables.
Use heroku:psql for that, e.g.

```
heroku pg:psql --app your_app DATABASE_URL
```

Then you can delete whatever you don't need, e.g:

```
DELETE FROM some_table WHERE some_column=some_value
```

You probably want to do a [Heroku PGBackup](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups) first, just in case you make a mistake.

If you need all the info in your DB to be available online, then you will need to upgrade your Heroku Postgres plan to a paid plan. For example, the [Hobby Basic](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql) plan increases your row limit to 10,000,000 rows at $9 / month.